# Sass force compile using terminal

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way to force sass to overwrite css files already generated. I already know compass does this but I really don't want to install compass for this simple setup. 
What I'm trying to do is minify all my files in one go. 
I was using this before. But with the watch command I would have to go into all 40 sass files and make a change in each one for it to update and compress. I'm hoping there is a command to update all or overwrite all. Can't find it in the sass docs.

```
sass --watch sass:../web-app/css --style compressed
```

Comment: Are you creating 40 css files? Is there a reason you aren't combining into one? If you're using sublime text, you could do a find/replace in all files in that folder using a space for both. Then save all the files.

Comment: The number of sass files is kind of irrelevant to my question here. I agree having all css in one file. Right now I just want to know if there is a command to update all files, Instead of using the --watch.

Comment: Gotcha. Based on my search, Sass itself doesn't. Have you tried deleting all the css files, then doing a watch? This recompiles everything without changing any files.

Comment: Yea I tried deleting one of the css files and then running watch again but it didn't re-generate the css file until I updated the sass file. Total pain in the butt :)

Comment: That's strange. I just did it with one and it generated the css file again. My scss files are in a different directory and my watch command is slightly different: `sass --watch scss/style.scss:style.css --style expanded`. I'm also explicitly naming the file. Not sure if any of that matters, but who knows. Maybe test those first two and see if affects anything. PITA indeed.

Comment: Yea the only difference is I'm watching the entire folder and not just one file. Ok I guess I'm going to have to install compass. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You simply want to use 'update' with 'force'

```
sass --update --force path/to/sass:path/to/css
```